# MDX query "with member" and sum problem

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a query like

```
   WITH MEMBER [measures].[Count] AS 
   SUM(([Location].[Hierarchy].[Zone].[1].Children),[Measures].[Length])
   SELECT {[measures].[Count]} ON 0,
   {[Location].[Hierarchy].[Zone].&[1].Children} on 1
   FROM [NTAP]
```

I'm a real beginner with MDX but from my understanding this should get me a list with all Zone 1:s children and a sum of all those children Length summarized. The problem is I get a list with the children and a sum of all Zone 1:s Length?

I get this:

```
1 103026769420
2 103026769420
3 103026769420
4 103026769420
```

But what I would like to get is something like this

```
1 84984958
2 9494949
3 934883
4 9458948588
```

Location is a hierarchy like:

Zone   Children

```
1
   1
   2
   3
2
   1
   2
   3
```

edit: should probably say that the reason I use **with member** is that the measure.length will with a **Iif** in the final version. But I cant even get this working :(

edit2: fixed spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the sum of all children of Zone 1 for each child of Zone 1.

You can rewrite it as:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS 
   SUM([Location].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Children, [Measures].[Length])
SELECT {[Measures].[Count]} ON 0,
   {[Location].[Hierarchy].[Zone].&[1].Children} on 1
FROM [NTAP]
```

By the way, [1] <> &[1]. Without the & you are specifying the name and with - the key. If in your case key = name you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: That did not work, all I got this time was 

    1   (null)
    2   (null)
    3   (null)
    4   (null)

Comment: Are there any children under the children of Zone 1? Or are they leaves? If they are leaves you won't get meaningful results. To fix you can change the query to:

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS 
   SUM([Location].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Length])
SELECT {[Measures].[Count]} ON 0,
   {[Location].[Hierarchy].[Zone].&[1].Children} on 1
FROM [NTAP]

Comment: Super Thanks, that was it, it was leaves under Zone 1.

I have a hard time to grasp why this works? To me it seems that CurrentMember in the working query is Zone 1 and not the leaves under it?

Comment: Well, you have the children of Zone 1 on ROWS axis. Therefore, the CurrentMember function will give you them instead of Zone 1 itself. By the way, you can skip the SUM call too. If you ask for the tuple of (location.currentmember, measure) you should get the same as you are working with one member only.

Comment: The reason from the beginning with SUM is that I would like to count the children of zone 1 with Length > 0 and was planning to use

SUM([Location].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember,Iif([Measures].[Length] > 0 ,1,0)

But that dont work, all I get is 1 on all rows, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

A query counting the children with L > 0 would be:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Children with L more than 0] AS
    FILTER([Location].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Children,
           [Measures].[Length] > 0).COUNT
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Count of Children with L more than 0]
} ON 0,
{
    [Location].[Hierarchy].[Zone].&[1]
} ON 1
FROM [Your Cube]
```

This of course won't work if you select the children on rows as then you'd get NULLs as they are leaves and have no children themselves.

Comment: Sorry I think I my naming of the measures is kind of bad, Measures.Length is actually not a single value under Zone 1.Children. There can actually be > 10000 Length values under each Zone 1.Children and I would like to count the number of Length values under each Child. Sorry My Wording Sucks...